# iFrame works in Chrome but not IE/Firefxx

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

http://www.starkgaming.com/moba

As I'm mostly done with my company's website (newly formed yay!) I'm having issues with my website only in IE and Firefox (I used chrome during development). My hover menu is working but within it is a tab system + iframe. The tab systems appears to be working as you can hover and click the "tabs" at the top. I believe the iframe flickers for a moment and then disappears.

**In Chrome, my website works fantastic.**

If I set the iframe to fixed you can see it behind the hover menu and the tab functionality works just fine, its just hidden behind the hover menu.

I've tried adjusting the z-index to see if that is an issue, no luck there.

I've tried setting the height to a flat number instead of % with no luck.

I also thought my JS was being handled weird but removing this portion still makes it operate the same so I feel this part is not the problem part of the code:

```
                $(".tab_content").show();
                $(".tab_content:first").show();
                $(".tab_content").addClass("active");
                $(".tab_content:nth-child(2)").hide();
                $(".tab_content:nth-child(3)").hide();
```

I've went to modern.ie and resolved most problems there.

Looked at a ton of A&Q on google for IE and firefox iframe issues.

Since trying to resolve these problems I've added the extended html doc type and meta charset, even a CSS Reset for the heck of it.

I'm fairly confident the z-index or something is not being handled properly so the iframe is being placed behind the hover menu but I can't be certain.

**The HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/moba/css/cssreset.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/moba/css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/moba/css/tabstyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0px" topmargin="50px">


    <div id="socialmedia">
    <div id="socialbordertop"></div>
    <center>
    <BR>
        <A TITLE="E-Mail" HREF="mailto:info@starkgaming.com"><IMG SRC="/moba/images/social-email-icon.png"></a>
        <A TITLE="Twitter" HREF="http://www.twitter.com/starkgaminginc"><IMG SRC="/moba/images/social-twitter-icon.png"></a>
        <A TITLE="Facebook" HREF="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Stark-Gaming-Inc/867749979955567"><IMG SRC="/moba/images/social-facebook-icon.png"></a>
        <A TITLE="Glassdoor" HREF="http://www.glassdoor.com/starkgaminginc"><IMG SRC="/moba/images/social-glassdoor-icon.png"></a>
        <A TITLE="AngelList" HREF="http://www.angel.co/stark-gaming-inc"><IMG SRC="/moba/images/social-angel-icon.png"></a>
        <A TITLE="LinkedIn" HREF="https://www.linkedin.com/company/stark-gaming-incorporated"><IMG SRC="/moba/images/social-linkedin-icon.png"></a>
                <BR>
    </center>
    </div>


    <div id="mainbgimage"></div>


    <div class="content"><!-- Menu Start -->
        <ul id="sdt_menu" class="sdt_menu">


            <li><!-- About Me Section Start -->

                <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                <span class="sdt_wrap">
                    <span class="sdt_link">Who We Are</span>
                    <span class="sdt_descr">Innovative Gaming</span>
                </span>
                    <div class="sdt_box"><!-- Drop Down Menu Box Start -->
                        <div id="bordertop"></div>
                        <div id="borderbottom"></div>
                        <div id="aboutusbg"></div>


                        <div id="container"><!-- About SG Tab System Start -->
                                <ul class="tabs"><!-- Tab Titles Start -->
                                    <li rel="play"></li>
                                    <li rel="analyze"></li>
                                    <li rel="create"></li>                                      
                                </ul><!-- Tab Titles End -->

                                <div class="tab_container"><!-- Tab Container Start -->

                                        <div id="play" class="tab_content"><!-- Tab1 Start -->
                                        <iframe ID="iframe" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="0" src="/moba/html/play-tab.html"></iframe>
                                        </div><!-- Tab1 End -->

                                        <div id="analyze" class="tab_content"><!-- Tab2 Start -->
                                        <iframe ID="iframe" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="0" src="/moba/html/analyze-tab.html"></iframe>
                                        </div><!-- Tab2 End -->

                                        <div id="create" class="tab_content"><!-- Tab3 Start -->
                                        <iframe ID="iframe" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="0" src="/moba/html/create-tab.html"></iframe>
                                        </div><!-- Tab3 End -->                                         

                                </div><!-- Tab Container End -->
                        </div><!-- About SG Tab System End -->

                    </div><!-- Drop Down Menu Box End -->
            </li><!-- About Me Section End -->  

            <li><!-- Career Start -->
                <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                <span class="sdt_wrap">
                    <span class="sdt_link">Career</span>
                    <span class="sdt_descr">Join Stark Gaming</span>
                </span>
                    <div class="sdt_box">
                    <div id="bordertop"></div>
                    <div id="borderbottom"></div>       


                    <div id="container"><!-- About SG Tab System Start -->

                                <ul class="tabs"><!-- Tab Titles Start -->
                                    <li rel="career"></li>                          
                                </ul><!-- Tab Titles End -->

                                <div class="tab_container"><!-- Tab Container Start -->

                                        <div id="career" class="tab_content"><!-- Tab1 Start -->
                                        <iframe ID="iframe" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="0" src="/moba/html/career-tab.html"></iframe>
                                        </div><!-- Tab1 End -->

                                </div><!-- Tab Container End -->
                    </div><!-- About SG Tab System End -->

                    </div>
            </li><!-- Career Start End -->              

            <li><!-- Dev Blog Start -->
                <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                <span class="sdt_wrap">
                    <span class="sdt_link">Dev Blog</span>
                    <span class="sdt_descr">Progress Updates</span>
                </span>
                    <div class="sdt_box">
                    <div id="bordertop"></div>
                    <div id="borderbottom"></div>   

                        <div id="container"><!-- Dev Blog Tab System Start -->

                                <ul class="tabs"><!-- Tab Titles Start -->
                                    <li rel="devblog"></li>         
                                </ul><!-- Tab Titles End -->

                                <div class="tab_container"><!-- Tab Container Start -->

                                        <div id="devblog" class="tab_content"><!-- Tab1 Start -->
                                        <iframe ID="iframe" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="0" src="/moba/html/devblog-tab.html"></iframe>
                                        </div><!-- Tab1 End -->

                                </div><!-- Tab Container End -->
                        </div><!-- Dev Blog System End -->

                    </div>
            </li><!-- Dev Blog End -->              


            <li><!-- Donate Start -->

                <span class="sdt_active"></span>
                <span class="sdt_wrap">
                    <span class="sdt_link">Donate</span>
                    <span class="sdt_descr">Help us</span>
                </span>
                    <div class="sdt_box">
                    <div id="bordertop"></div>
                    <div id="borderbottom"></div>   


                        <div id="container"><!-- Donate Tab System Start -->

                                <ul class="tabs"><!-- Tab Titles Start -->
                                    <li rel="donate"></li>                              
                                </ul><!-- Tab Titles End -->

                                <div class="tab_container"><!-- Tab Container Start -->

                                        <div id="donate" class="tab_content"><!-- Tab1 Start -->
                                        <iframe ID="iframe" SCROLLING="no" FRAMEBORDER="0" src="/moba/html/donate-tab.html"></iframe>
                                        </div><!-- Tab1 End -->

                                </div><!-- Tab Container End -->
                        </div><!-- Donate System End -->

                    </div>
            </li><!-- Donate End -->        


        </ul>
    </div><!-- Menu End --> 











    <!-- The JavaScript -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/moba/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js">     </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function() {


                $(".tab_content").show();
                $(".tab_content:first").show();
                $(".tab_content").addClass("active");
                $(".tab_content:nth-child(2)").hide();
                $(".tab_content:nth-child(3)").hide();  

                $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
                    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".tab_content").hide();
                    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
                    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn(250); 
                });
            }); 


        $(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */



            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){   
                var $elem = $(this);

                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'190px',
                        'height':'85px',
                        'left':'0px',
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                        .animate({'top':'-43px','left':'0px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},0,function(){


                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){

                        $sub_menu.fadeIn(250);


                    }   

                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){

                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.fadeOut(500);9

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'0px'},500);
            });
        });



</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**The CSS (main page)**

```
body {
background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bg/rotate.php);
overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x:hidden;  
background-color: #FFF;
background-repeat: no-repeat;   
background-size: cover;
}

#socialmedia{
background-image:    url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgblacktransparent.png);
background-repeat: repeat;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top:30px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 70px;
Width: 100%;
position: fixed;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 0;
}

#iframe{
background: transparent;
background-repeat: repeat;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
height: 400px;
Width: 100%;
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 5000;
}

#socialbordertop{
background-color: #11b0b2;
background-repeat: repeat;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 3px;
Width: 100%;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 2000;
}

#mainbgimage{
background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/mainbgimage.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
width: 665px;
height: 150px;
top: 350px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
overflow: visible;
z-index: -2000;
}

#bordertop{
background-color: #11b0b2;
background-repeat: repeat;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 3px;
Width: 100%;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 2000;
}

#borderbottom{
background-color: #11b0b2;
background-repeat: repeat;
left: 0px;
top: 397px;
height: 3px;
Width: 100%;
position: absolute;
overflow: visible;
z-index: 2000;
}



ul.sdt_menu{
margin-top: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
padding:0;
list-style: none;
font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
width:760px;
color:#FFF;
text-align: center;
}
ul.sdt_menu a{
text-decoration:none;
outline:none;

}
ul.sdt_menu li{
float:left;
width:190px;
height:85px;
position:relative;
cursor:pointer;

}
ul.sdt_menu li > a{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:190px;
height:85px;
z-index:12;
background:transparent url(../images/overlay.png) no-repeat bottom right;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #000 inset;
}
ul.sdt_menu li a img{
border:none;
position:absolute;
width:0px;
height:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:85px;
z-index:100;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_wrap{
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:190px;
height:40px;
z-index:15;
background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/wrapbg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul.sdt_menu li span.sdt_active{
position:absolute;
background:#111;
top:85px;
width:190px;
height:0px;
left:0px;
z-index: 10;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
box-shadow:0px 0px 4px #000 inset;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link,
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr,
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
margin-left:0px;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;


}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_link{

color: #13b6b8;
font-size:15px;
float:center;
clear:both;

}
ul.sdt_menu li span span.sdt_descr{
color:#000;
float:left;
clear:both;
width:190px; /*For dumbass IE7*/
font-size:15px;
letter-spacing:1px;
z-index: 15;

}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box{
position:fixed;
display:block;
height:400px;
overflow:hidden;
width: 100%;    
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 100px;
display:none;
background-color: #000;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a{
float:left;
clear:both;
line-height:0px;
color:#0B75AF;

}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:first-child{
margin-top:0px;

}
ul.sdt_menu li div.sdt_box a:hover{
color:#fff;

}
```

**The CSS (TABS)**

```
    #play.tab_content {
    background-image:    url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgtest1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px -500px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    Width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: -1;
    }

    #analyze.tab_content{
    background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgtest2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px -50px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    Width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: -1;
    }

    #create.tab_content{
    background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgtest3.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px -500px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    Width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: -1;
    }

    #career.tab_content{
    background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgtest5.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px -500px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    Width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: -1;
    }

    #devblog.tab_content{
    background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/devblogbg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px -50px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    Width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: -1;
    }

    #donate.tab_content{
    background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgtest4.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px -250px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    Width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: -1;
}

    #tabboxblack{
    background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgblacktransparent50.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;    
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 70%;
    Width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 5010;
    }   

    #tabboxwhite{
    background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgwhitetransparent10.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;        
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 90%;
    Width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 5010;
    }   

    #tabboxtransparent{
    background: transparent;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;    
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 70%;
    Width: 90%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 5010;
    }   

    #tabtitle {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: -75px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    }

    #tabarrow {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    }   

    ul.tabs {
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top:0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 400px;
    Width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;   
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #FFF;
    z-index: 5001;

    }


    ul.tabs li {

    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 33.33%;  
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40;
    font-family: "Century Schoolbook";
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 5002;  

    }

    ul.tabs li:hover {
    color: #11b0b2;
    background-image: url(http://www.starkgaming.com/moba/images/bgwhitetransparent10.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    }   
    ul.tabs li.active{
    color: #11b0b2;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
    }

    .tab_container {
    border-top: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 5003;
    }

    .tab_content {
    position:absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;       
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
    top: 20%;
    z-index: 5004;

    }

    #container {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 400px;
    Width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px;
    z-index: 5005;      
    }
```

**Minor CSS for iframe pages:**

```
body {
overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x:hidden;  
background-repeat: repeat;
background-color: transparent;
font-family:"Myriad Pro", "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reversing the structure of my layout.

Instead of the iframe in the tab system, I made the tab system in my iframe.

This made it work, with some minor fixes needed for correct table positioning in firefox. Now working with IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

To properly position elements in firefox with a table, i did this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #firefox {
    vertical-align:top;
    padding-top: 60px;

    }
    }
    </style>
```

Made it work atleast for now, some work was needed to manage it but overall it will have to do... for now.